# Difference between Set and Bag in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

What is the main difference between the `Set` and `Bag` collections in Hibernate? 
In what scenarios should we use `Set` and `Bag`?

Comment: Read the documentation of `List` and `Set` interfaces.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A `<bag>` is an unordered collection, which can contain duplicated elements. That means if you persist a bag with some order of elements, you cannot expect the same order retains when the collection is retrieved. There is not a “bag” concept in Java collections framework, so we just use a `java.util.List` corresponds to a `<bag>`.

A `<set>` is similar to `<bag>` except that it can only store unique objects. That means no duplicate elements can be contained in a set. When you add the same element to a set for second time, it will replace the old one. A set is unordered by default but we can ask it to be sorted. The corresponding type of a  in Java is `java.util.Set`.

Examples

Mapping `<set>`

```
 <set name="employees" table="employee"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="department_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee" />
    </set>
```

Mapping `<bag>`

```
  <bag name="employees" table="employee"
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="employee_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee" />
        </bag>
```

Thus, both are mapped exactly same way in hbm file. But differs only in the way it handles duplicate records.

Source: [Hibernate One to Many XML Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/)

Comment: In case of annotations, where and what should be the mapping attribute to mark the collection of bag type??

Comment: For e.g if i have `@OneToMany(mappedBy="Dept") private List<Employee> employees;` in Department entity. how can i mark the collection type as bag with annotations??

Comment: It's not true in Java that an element will be replaced in a set if you try to add a duplicate as mentioned above: "add the same element to a set for second time, it will replace the old one". It's not clear to me If the author is writing about a Hibernate specific behavior that I'm not aware of however.

Answer (score 8):

From the Hibernate reference:

> Bags are the worst case since they permit duplicate element values and, as they have no index
>   column, no primary key can be defined. Hibernate has no way of distinguishing between duplicate rows.

And also:

> There is a particular case, however, in which bags, and also lists, are much more performant than
>   sets. For a collection with `inverse="true"`, the standard bidirectional one-to-many relationship idiom, for example, we can add elements to a bag or list without needing to initialize (fetch) the bag elements.

Answer (score 7):

Quick Summary difference between the various collections is as below

- **Set** - No duplicates and No order
- **Bag** - Can contain Duplicates and No Order (Also called, Unordered List or Set with duplicates)
- **List** - Can contain Duplicates but with Order preserved

  - Can be created using @OrderBy to preserve order

Answer (score 2):

Both are unordered collections. Bags allow duplicates. Sets do not.